# Error building openJDK 11 with devkit: Unknown base OS Fedora

Tags: java, openjdk-11

I need to build the following openJDK

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch jdk-11+28 https://github.com/openjdk/jdk.git
```

For that I run:

```
cd make/devkit
make TARGETS="aarch64-linux-gnu" BASE_OS=Fedora BASE_OS_VERSION=21 &>build.log
```

And got following error

```
Building on platform x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_platforms x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
target_platforms x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
find: ‘/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit/result/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu’: No such file or directory
Building compilers for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Targets: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
for p in x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu ; do \
  make -f Tools.gmk download-rpms HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu BUILD=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu RESULT=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit/result PREFIX=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit/result/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu OUTPUT_ROOT=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit TARGET=$p && \
  make -f Tools.gmk all HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu BUILD=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu RESULT=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit/result PREFIX=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit/result/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu OUTPUT_ROOT=/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/build/devkit \
      TARGET=$p || exit 1 ; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/make/devkit'
TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
BUILD=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ARCH=x86_64
Tools.gmk:66: *** Unknown base OS Fedora.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/katya/e947f05e-bd8f-4647-bbdd-0df608faa788/openjdk11/jdk/make/devkit'
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' failed
make: *** [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] Error 1
```

Host OS is Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus). Please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Where can I submit a bug report about openjdk11, or discuss this issue?

Comment: host is not fedora, it is ubuntu. change BASE_OS=Fedora to ubuntu.

Comment: id is devkit it don't care about host OS as I understand. Anyway there are only two BASE_OSes available : Fedora and OEL (Oracle Enterprise Linux)

Comment: In that case, you would probably need to build on Fedora and then run the devkit on Ubuntu. That is possible as per the docs - "You can for example create and use a devkit with GCC 7.3 and a Fedora 12 sysroot environment (with glibc 2.11) on Ubuntu 14.04"

Comment: @Khanna111 I am creating Fedora 21 environment and it doesn't matter what is my host os (Ubuntu 16 in my case) am I wrong?

Comment: Seems like, you need to make on fedora and use it on Ubuntu...